# STL vector of pointers will not compile

Tags: pointers, vector, stl

I think I have C++ 98...
I want to create pointers to existing objects and then store those pointers in a vector. This is my code and the compiler barks:

```
  vector<long double> *p1;
  p1=&vOPCT;
  vector<long double> *p2;
  p2=&vOPCGas;

  vector<long double *> MyVec;
  MyVec.push_back(p1);   <- error
  MyVec.push_back(p2);   <- error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated..
Fred E.

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are of type `vector<long double> *`, **not** `long double *` which is the payload type of `MyVec`.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<long double *> MyVec;
MyVec.push_back(p1);   <- error
```

You're attempting to put a pointer to a vector (`vector< long double>*`) into a vector of pointers to long double (`vector< long double *>`). That's not going to work.

This should work:

```
vector<long double *> MyVec;
long double *p1 = nullptr;
MyVec.push_back(p1);
```

Comment: My pointer p1, points to an existing object (vOPCT), which is a vector of long doubles. I can get that part to work.  I have *many* other objects I want to set pointers to. The end game is to be able to iterate through the pointers (and thus objects) to be able to resize the vector objects. This was my idea on how to do it. Apparently a vector of pointers is not going to work the way I tried. So is my code attempting to set up a vector of pointers to long doubles, or pointers to vectors of long doubles?

Comment: Your code is attempting to set up a vector of pointers to long doubles (the former).  If you want to set up a vector of pointers to vectors of long doubles, (the latter), then `MyVec` should be declared as `vector<vector<long double> *>`

Comment: Okay, now I see it! Thanks for the help!